# Injecting Code Into Linq

Tags: linq

I want to transform foreach to Linq

```
foreach (var e in  x.Root.Element("Body").Elements())
{
   Block b = new Block();
   b.Text = e.Element("Text").Value;
   b.RadioButtons = e.Element("RadioButtons").Elements().Select(j => j.Value.ToString()).ToList();
   m.BlockList.Add(b);
}
```

Can I place some code into Linq query?

Comment: And suddenly, everything is a nail.

Comment: You gots Linq in there already : `e.Element("RadioButtons").Elements().Select(j => j.Value.ToString()).ToList()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is exactly what you're looking for, but this should work:

```
var bodyElements = x.Root.Element("Body").Elements()).Select(e => new Block
        {
            Text = e.Element("Text").Value,
            RadioButtons = e.Element("RadioButtons").Elements().Select(j => j.Value.ToString()).ToList()
        }).ToList();

        m.BlockList.AddRange(bodyElements);
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 4):

Why? This is code is very readable and has side effects. It should remain as a `foreach` loop.

Comment: There are no side-effects, it's just projection.

Comment: @David B: There's a collection being modified.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do that is to [project](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/aa336758.aspx) a new `Block` object in your LINQ query:

```
m.BlockList = (
    from e in x.Root.Element("Body").Elements()
    select new Block {
        Text = e.Element("Text").Value,
        RadioButtons = (
            from j in e.Element("RadioButtons").Elements()
            select j.Value.ToString()
        ).ToList(),
    }
).ToList();
```

If `m.BlockList` already contains items and you want to preserve them, if it supports [AddRange()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z883w3dc.aspx) you can do:

```
m.BlockList.AddRange(
    from e in x.Root.Element("Body").Elements()
    select new Block {
        Text = e.Element("Text").Value,
        RadioButtons = (
            from j in e.Element("RadioButtons").Elements()
            select j.Value.ToString()
        ).ToList(),
    });
```

The others are right, though: your code is probably fine as it is.

Comment: Actually this is more readable -- the making of the `m` list is not as hidden now.  It does not do exactly the same thing if `m` already had elements.

Comment: @Hogan, you're right. I don't know if `m.BlockList` supports `AddRange()`, though.